# Jetty 9.4 starts two jvms on startup

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

It is advised to use jetty.base  [Managing Jetty Base and Jetty Home](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/startup-base-and-home.html)

> Instead of managing multiple Jetty implementations out of several different distribution locations, it is possible to maintain a separation between the binary installation of the standalone Jetty (known as ${jetty.home}), and the customizations for your specific environment(s) (known as ${jetty.base}). There should always only be one Jetty Home (per version of Jetty), but there can be multiple Jetty Base directories that reference it.

I setup jetty like the following structure

```
/jetty-9.4.3
 ├──start.jar
 ├── ... 
/mybase
 ├── start.ini
 ├── ... 
 ├── run.bat
```

under mybase run.bat has the following script

```
SET JETTY_HOME="../jetty-9.4.3"
echo %JETTY_HOME%
java -jar %JETTY_HOME%/start.jar -Xmx768m -Djetty.base=. -DSTOP.PORT=9999 -DSTOP.KEY=rwos &
```

when I execute `start.bat` jetty launches **two jvms** whereas if I directly run `java -jar start.jar` from `jetty.home` it launches one jvm.

Is there any specific reason.

The following is the config of `/mybase/start.ini`

```
--module=ext
--module=logging-logback
--module=http
jetty.http.port=8088
--module=resources
--module=deploy
```

[image]
Also it takes more memory 4.1GB than allotted 768M. Need to resolve these two issues.

jetty --list-config output is kept here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfwwwhkh0gwdxll/config.txt?dl=0

Comment: from `/mybase/` run the following ... `java -jar ../jetty-9.4.3/start.jar --list-config` and report its output in your question.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt attached, looks like I need to set -Xmx in start.ini  rather than command line script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an `--exec` line in your `/mybase/start.ini`

That will fork a JVM to pass in the JVM options you are specifying.

If your configuration seen in `--list-config` shows entries for **JVM Arguments** then those are going to force a forked JVM via the *exec* techniques.

Your `--list-config` shows ...

```
Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.4.3.v20170317
 jetty.tag.version = master
 jetty.home = /opt/prod-server/nm_jetty/jetty-9.4.3
 jetty.base = /opt/prod-server/nm_jetty/roy-comp-jetty/.

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> /opt/prod-server/nm_jetty/roy-comp-jetty/.
 ${jetty.home} -> /opt/prod-server/nm_jetty/jetty-9.4.3


JVM Arguments:
--------------
 -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class?=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog

System Properties:
------------------
 STOP.KEY = stop-roy-comp
 STOP.PORT = 15041
 conf.dir = .
 jetty.base = .

Properties:
-----------
 STOP.KEY = stop-roy-comp
 STOP.PORT = 15041
 conf.dir = .
 java.version = 1.8.0_65
 java.version.major = 1
 java.version.micro = 0
 java.version.minor = 8
 java.version.platform = 8
 java.version.update = 65
 jetty.base = /opt/prod-server/nm_jetty/roy-comp-jetty/.
 jetty.http.port = 15040
 jetty.webapp.addServerClasses = ${jetty.base.uri}/lib/slf4j/,${jetty.base.uri}/lib/logback/
 logback.version = 1.1.7
 slf4j.version = 1.7.21
```

And if [we look at the `logging-logback` module you have enabled](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.3.v20170317/jetty-util/src/main/config/modules/logging-logback.mod#L15-L16) we'll see...

```
[exec]
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class?=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```

Comment: I didnt add `--exec` in start.ini. start.ini crated using `--add-to-start` option

Comment: If I stop jetty using `--stop` it terminates both jvms but if user killed jvm manually or close batch cmd, one jvm remains alive.

Comment: I've updated my question, process takes memory than allotted. Is there other config may required

Comment: Yes, module `--module=logging-logback` is included via `start.ini`. Is there any alternate ?